# Computer won't power on at all

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, desktop-computer

So, this morning I woke up and my computer won't power on *at all.* There's no beeps, no lights (though I don't think my motherboard has lights on it anyways?). I plugged in my brother's PSU and it still didn't work. I also tried plugging my PSU into his computer and his turned on fine.

How likely is it that this is the motherboard? I checked the "on switch" on the front panel, and the wires are hot glued (or something) into there. I just don't want to spend the money on a motherboard and have it turn out to not be the problem.

I REALLY don't know much about computers, so I don't know much specs. I'm sorry.

Comment: Just to eliminate the outlet as a potential problem, did you check that a breaker or fuse did not get tripped? Although you said you swapped PSUs, you did not state that you used the same power outlet. It is always good to check the basics first. Then it can be narrowed down to computer components. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe I understand from your description that there is power TO the computer.

1) Check the power cord to ensure it is seated properly in the power supply on the back of the computer.

2) Check the back of the computer, there may be a rocker switch on the back of the power supply, be sure it is on.

The problem is more likely in the power supply than the motherboard.

Comment: The power cord is in fine, and the switch to set to normal (even tried flipping it back and forth a few times, which didn't work). We hooked up my brother's power supply to my computer even and it still didn't work, even though it works for his computer fine. Hooked my power supply up to my brother's computer, and his turned on just fine too.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that the switch on the tower case is broke.

If you unplug the power pins from the motherboard, you can bypass the case switch. Typically, the connectors or the motherboard are marked as to which connector is for the power switch. I've always used a small screwdriver to touch the two power pins together, but a small wire would suffice as well. Make sure you are very careful not to touch anything else on the motherboard.

If it powers up, it is the case switch. If it doesn't power up, you've at least eliminated the switch as a possibility.